# Delete a set of strings in a list in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to solve the below problem in simplest way using python code:

```
a = ['one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','nine']
b = ['three','seven','nine']
```

How can I remove only the elements of b from a:

I need a to be -->

```
A=['one', 'two', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'eight']
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a list comprehension to build a new list:

```
A = [elem for elem in a if elem not in b]
```

This would be more efficient if you made `b` a set:

```
b = set(b)
```

as membership testing (`in` and `not in`) is far faster for sets than it is for lists, where every contained item has to be tested individually.

Demo:

```
>>> a = ['one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','nine']
>>> b = ['three','seven','nine']
>>> b = set(b)
>>> b
set(['seven', 'nine', 'three'])
>>> [elem for elem in a if elem not in b]
['one', 'two', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'eight']
```

Comment: Or, if both are sets he could do just `a - b`. It doesn't stay sorted of course.

Comment: @JuriRobl: at the expense of losing ordering, yes.

Comment: Thnx a lot Martijn and juri .  If i were to delete elements in list a , how do i do it ??

Comment: @Ramesh: Just re-assign the list comprehension to `a[:]` to replace just the elements; `a[:] = [elem for elem in a if elem not in b]`. That leaves the list bound so *other* references to the same list will see the changes as well.

Answer (score 0):

Convert them to set and find the difference.

```
>>> a = ['one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','nine']
>>> b = ['three','seven','nine']
>>> print (list(set(a)-set(b))) #converted to list,since you want the output as list.
['two', 'eight', 'one', 'five', 'six', 'four']
>>>
```

Comment: Thnx for that.  But i don wanna change the order :)

Comment: @Ramesh You don't. they're already still list. Define another variable `difference = list(set(a)-set(b))`. So they'll still lists.